# get displayed data of a website and store the data in your firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I know how to get displayed data of someone's website  and display it in my Flutter app. But don't know how to get the displayed data and store it in my firebase firestore. is it possible to get the displayed data from a website and store it in my firebase firestore???

[image]

Comment: You can't directly access the data of website. But instead you can check if there's any api calls which sends the data

Comment: yeah i know, but i don't know how to do it

Comment: can you please help me to do this???

Comment: @Ashish Need more help

Comment: You may want to use the [`add` method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/web-scraping-in-flutter/) to save data that you get from a website scraping, described in [this guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/web-scraping-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FlutterFire.
FlutterFire is a set of Flutter plugins which connect your Flutter application to Firebase.

https://firebase.flutter.dev

See docs for firestore:

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview

Comment: this is not what i mean

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).